# Fields of the Message class

Tags: android, message

Which fields of the Message class which should be used to store custom message codes about the Message? 
 Please any one tell me fields of the message class which used for store custom message.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can store your message codes in arg1 and arg2 of message object.... U can also store your message data in object field of message.. like below

```
String str= "Message content";
Message ms = new Message();
ms.arg1 =0;
ms.arg2 = 1;
ms.obj = str;
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, I am sure that we can store message codes in arg1 and arg2 but Is it sure that we store in object fields?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html

public int what
Added in API level 1

User-defined message code so that the recipient can identify what this message is about. Each Handler has its own name-space for message codes, so you do not need to worry about yours conflicting with other handlers.